# How can access from Kibana several Elasticsearch instances in different machines?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I would like to have two Eleasticsearch instances in different machines accessible from the same Kibana instance. 
Something like this:

[image: Kibana instance]

Do you know how could I do it? 
My first idea is to create a cluster with two nodes, how could I create a cluster with nodes with different machines?
Which parameter should I change from Elasticsearch config file ?

Comment: Elasticsearch is designed to be distributed. Running ES on different machines is pretty much a standard use case. I mean honestly if you read the docs, you're gonna find your answer.

Comment: Are you trying to build a two-node cluster, or have kibana run against two clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElasticSearch contains Discovery Module:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html

by default Multicast  discovery is used. This means  ES  will be searching across  your network  any another ES instances ( in common terms). You can read more about of   discovery types  supported in article above.

Also  you can manually  specify  hosts, that should be in a cluster:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ "host1:9300", "host2:9300" ...  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define

`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.45.21", "192.168.45.22"]`

An example is described [here](https://www.devops.zone/solr-elasticsearch/installing-an-elasticsearch-cluster-with-2-nodes/)

Detailed configuration info should be [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)